# Generalized polynomial matrix

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, reference-request, matrix-calculus

I am searching for a keyword that would open the door to further readings.
A polynomial matrix is an object of the form

$\mathcal{A}(x) = A_0 + A_1x + A_2 x^2 + \ldots + A_n x^n$

where the $\lbrace A_i \rbrace$ are all $m\times k$ matrices.

What is the name of the following object?

$\mathscr{A}(x) = A_0 + A_1 \phi_1(x) + A_2 \phi_2(x) + \ldots + A_n \phi_n(x)$

where the $\lbrace\phi_i(x)\rbrace$ are (at least) linearly independent scalar functions on the variable $x$ (they could be orthogonal, as in Fourier basis).

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: So far I have found some characterization of general analytic matrix functions in Chapter S6 of *Matrix Polynomials* by I. Gohberg, P. Lancaster, L. Rodman. Although analytic matrix function does not describe the structure given above, I guess one can go with that name.

Comment: What name would you suggest for these beasts if one replaced the matrices by scalars (so you're just linearly combining your "independent scalar functions")?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen In the scalar case if we allow $n \rightarrow \infty$ the it would be a generalized Fourier series. For finite $n$, "truncated generalized Fourier series"? Basically the resulting matrix has the entries in the linear span of $\lbrace \phi_i \rbrace$. Have this matrices been studied somewhere? How would you search for literature? I am interested in their kernel.